# Best way to ensure the call / receive of a broadcast in power saving mode?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

So I was trying different approaches to make sure my app handles a task every night in the background.
My current approach is using the AlarmManager and it works (in the virtual machine) pretty fine, unless I turn on the power saving mode.

I already found a workaround by allowing the app to be ignored in power saving mode, but this approach requires user interaction, which i'm not really a fan of in that case.

Is there any other way to deal with this problem?
Perhaps one, that doesnt require user interaction?

Comment: Do you have to perform in specific time? If not, than switch to WorkManager.

Comment: Well the task needs to execute once per day. Optimal case would be the execution to be around midnight. The problem with WorkManager i had was a little shifting time, so once it was at 00:00 the next time at 00:01 and so forth. Which means in about a year it would be somewhere in the middle of the day which is not good .

Comment: Do you have plenty of data? I had this exact problem about midnight and I made a WorkManager switch by just synchronising every 22 hours or so. You can use `PeriodicRequest`s

Comment: does the WorkManager work better in power saving mode? and how do i make sure it gets executed at around the same time? Because the task somewhat relates to the day switchting

Comment: You can just fire an `AlarmManager` in a time like 00:00 and start a `WorkManager` there or you can just find the difference between midnight and current time and place the initial delay. Well, `WorkManager` is safer than all the other API's about background scheduling. However for exact timing `AlarmManager` is the only solution you have yet. `WorkManager` is made to respect dose mode.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly i should do the normal alarmmanager / receiver setup and call a workmanager in the receiver? or does the AlarmManager just setup an Intent which somewhat contains a WorkManager? Sorry im pretty confused right now

Comment: 1 option is what you mention: Fire alarm at 00:00 and start `WorkManager` in there.
2 The other one is just to start the `WorkManager` from the activity/fragment with initial delay from (midnighttime - currenttime). 
3 Stick to repeating `AlarmManager` at exact timing. 
If you choose 3 you have to program another receiver to detect device start in order to reschedule the alarm of sync.

Comment: But i still would need an initial working alarmmanager to use option 1 right? Because in that case, it doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: No just fire the alarm once and you are done! Inside it start a `PeriodicWorkRequest` and after that your `WorkManager` will run. But this is a little dangerous, because if the user forces stop of the app, there is no way to restart your work manager again. So I would stick to option 2 and sync every 22 hrs

Comment: Well i Just tested it and it doesnt work in power saving mode. I can't even send one onetimerequest. It's getting set but never executes in like a timing area of like 10 minutes

Comment: what if you set require charge false as a constraint?

Comment: How would and where would i add that? At the creation of the OneTimeBuilder? Or just as a wrapping if?

Comment: constraints of the work manager